# Is there a query which selects columns from only one table which would give incorrect results if grouped by only the primary key of that table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

For example, a bookpub database contains the following tables (pseudocode):

```
book (key: isbn)
bookauthor (key:author_id, isbn)
author (key: author_id)
```

The following query returns the number of books by each author:

```
select lastname, firstname, count(isbn)
from author
join bookauthor using (author_id)
group by lastname, firstname;
```

However, the following query also produces identical results in MySQL without complaint:

```
select lastname, firstname, count(isbn)
from author
join bookauthor using (author_id)
group by author_id;
```

So why shouldn't `author_id` be used instead of `lastname, firstname`?

I might add that the formal SQL spec contains the following:

```
All non-aggregate groups in a SELECT expression list or HAVING expression list must be included in the GROUP BY clause.
```

Can somebody please interpret this? What is a "non-aggregate group"? Why not just say "columns"? Furthermore, what is an "expression list"? Does an expression in this case always evaluate to a column?

Comment: Believe it or not, it is possible for two people to share the same name. So author_id should always be used! (Unless you just want to know how many books have beeen written by people called David Mitchell, say)

Comment: ha ha ... my neighboring room student had same name and initial as mine ... he used to receive my letters.

Comment: Personally, I think ISBN is a poor key. Broadly speaking, I don’t think keys should have any meaning out in the real world, beyond the scope of the database.

Comment: Indeed, there's no reason not to just group by the primary key; I don't know why other DBMSes don't allow it. Though it's worth noting that MySQL lets you do it even in cases where it *doesn't* make sense -- cases where the group-by expression *isn't* a primary key -- so the common factor across all DBMSes is that none of them has logic to check whether this makes sense.

Comment: @ruakh My sentiments exactly. I find it extremely interesting that major DBMS implementations lack this basic sophistication even at this late age.

Comment: @ruakh It isn't be implemented because it doesn't make sense.  In our example, if you have AuthorId, FirstName, LastName in SELECT, but only GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, which AuthorId to get if you have more than one row??  MIN(AuthorId)? MAX(AuthorID)?

Comment: @strawberry - depends on the key.  If you're specifically talking about a surrogate key *(such as an autoincrement or identity column)* then I agree.  Entities in a database may have external identities / keys, and they may indeed have meaning beyond being a unique identifier.

Comment: @matbailie indeed they may; I just don’t think they should- but I accept that that’s not a universally held view.

Comment: @TomRussel It's powerful and elegant.  It's also error prone and can cause silent failures, especially as schema / queries grow and change.  Pointers are extremely versatile and powerful, but they don't have a place in high level languages (opinion), similarly many people (including me) consider the benefits of this to be dramatically out weighed by the potential for issues.  *(I prefer to fail fast and fail hard, and this flexibility prevents that.)*

Comment: @Eric: You have that backward -- the example has the primary key (`author_id`) in the `GROUP BY` clause, which then uniquely determines the other fields (such as `lastname` and `firstname`).

Comment: @ruakh In this case it will work out.  But in general case, it's the reason why it's not implemented.  If the value is not unique, there's no deterministic way to select the non-aggregated columns accurately.  Is it supposed to be MIN, MAX, AVG.  That's the reason all non-aggregated columns must appear in GROUP BY.

Comment: @Eric: If you didn't even read my original comment, then why did you pretend you were replying to it?

Answer (score 2):

No SQL Implementation is 100% true to the ANSI definition.  Some things are missing, some things are added, something are just different.

In MySQL's case, it was chosen to not enforce the restriction you mention:

- All non-aggregate groups in a SELECT expression list or HAVING expression list must be included in the GROUP BY clause.

This allows the `GROUP BY primary_key` syntax that you have noticed, instead of the clunky *(and actually slightly more costly)* `GROUP BY property1, property2, property3, etc`.  It's clean and elegant.

There are downsides, however; misuse and misunderstanding are rife in web developers because of MySQL, and the flexibility allows bugs to slip though undetected.  I recommend avoiding it it in most cases as the performance gains are minimal and the potential for bugs can be huge.

An example of an bug that slips through could be:

```
SELECT
    person.name,
    address.city
FROM
    person
INNER JOIN
    address
        ON  address.person_id = person.id
GROUP BY
    person.id
```

MySQL will pretty much *always* allow that code to execute.  Even if the address table can have multiple entries per person (I've lived at more than one address).

The code could possibly need to be as follows, but MySQL will never enforce this:

```
SELECT
    person.name,
    address.move_in_date,
    address.city
FROM
    person
INNER JOIN
    address
        ON  address.person_id = person.id
GROUP BY
    person.id,
    address.id
```

The more joins involved, the more chance the `GROUP BY` needs to include multiple primary keys, or other fields.

The behavior you get is that MySQL arbitrarily chooses what values to return when the code is ambiguous.  It is explicitly non-deterministic.  The following code could give the city from one address and the city's population from another address :-/

```
SELECT
    person.name,
    address.move_in_date,
    address.city,
    city.population
FROM
    person
INNER JOIN
    address
        ON  address.person_id = person.id
INNER JOIN
    city
        ON  address.city_id = city.id
GROUP BY
    person.id
```

People then try to abuse this with "tricks" like the following...

```
SELECT
    person.name,
    address.move_in_date,
    address.city,
    city.population
FROM
    person
INNER JOIN
    address
        ON  address.person_id = person.id
INNER JOIN
    city
        ON  address.city_id = city.id
GROUP BY
    person.id
ORDER BY
    person.id,
    city.population DESC
```

This ***happens*** to cause the MySQL engine to choose the city with the highest population.  Useful for finding the most populous city each person has lived in?  Well, it's not actually guaranteed to work.  It's still arbitrary; if the tables are being written to, or the database is in a distributed environment, or the MySQL code changes, etc, the behavior could change.

But people do it anyway.  Because "well, it's always worked for me so far!"...

Comment: Nice answer. It's not quite what I'm asking, of course, since it involves selecting columns from more than one table. But informative nonetheless. I guess I might imply from your answer that, yes, grouping by the primary key or other unique column(s) will always suffice.

Comment: It depends on the situation, but where one field is as unique as some other composite of other fields, yes.

Comment: If you like to extrapolate my question to selecting columns from two or more tables, showing that including the primary key from each table in the `group by` produces desired results (or not) I'll be happy to credit your answer.

Comment: It's almost axiomatic.  A primary key is only a primary key if it uniquely identifies a row in a table.  Including a primary key in a `GROUP BY` clause there for *means* each group can't have data from multiple rows from that primary key's table.  The same row may appear multiple times in a group, but it would always be the same row, by definition.  Where there are multiple copies of the row, MySQL *arbitrarily* picks one of them.  No matter what *arbitrary* method is used to pick a value from `{x,x,x,x,x}`, it's always going to be `x`...

Comment: The only time a reference to a field could possibly give non-deterministic results is if there are multiple *different* rows in a group.  Which can only happen if the field you've grouped by doesn't have unique values. But if you've grouped by a unique identifier...  I'm struggling to make it clearer...

Comment: OK. But doesn't this beg the question as to why one wouldn't always use the tables' unique columns and *only* these in a `group by` clause?

Comment: I've answered that in my answer.  It masks mistakes, introducing a type of silent failures where previously there would have been error messages.  Yes it is elegant and powerful, but I'd rather have robustness.  So I recommend against using it *(turning on the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY option, which from 5.7.5 is ON by default, so even MySQL now implicitly recommends against its use)*.  Plus the examples of mis-understanding and mis-use.  So, why NOT use this shorthand?  Because ***it's Really Bad Practice***, and ***you have the option to turn it off***...

Answer (score 0):

In the group by clause you list fields and expressions whose values will partition your result set. For those groups you can calculate aggregate functions like count sum etc.
MySQL lets you select non aggregate expressions or fields, not present in the group by clause, but it's non standard SQL. The result will be non deterministic if those fields have more than one value for a group.

If you group by the primary key the result will be deterministic because there's only one row for each key.